# Make "mesh" a synonym of the "mesh-analysis" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

We had a tag called "mesh" but it had no tag wiki. I reviewed all 80 questions it was on and found that 75 of them referred to mesh analysis. Consequently, I removed "mesh" from the 5 questions that were not about mesh analysis, renamed the tag to [mesh-analysis](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mesh-analysis), and added a tag wiki.

Since users who type "mesh" in the list of tags almost always use it in the context of mesh analysis, **should we make "mesh" a synonym of [mesh-analysis](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mesh-analysis) so that the question would be automatically tagged correctly in those cases?** On the other hand, it's possible that someone might be referring to "mesh" in a different context as in the 5 questions from which I removed "mesh".

Of the 5 questions which were tagged with "mesh" but were not about mesh analysis, 3 were about [mesh networking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesh_networking):

- [BLE mesh Provisioning](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/412209/51760)
- [Mesh Thread network using Sub-1GHz](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/379741/51760)
- [Mesh WiFi ESP32-C3](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/624653/51760)

and 2 were about mesh wires:

- [Mesh Wire opening size for EMI filter at frequency of 30 MHz](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/505587/51760)
- [Randomize PCB trace generation with Altium Designer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/546573/51760)

**Should new "mesh-network" (or "mesh-networking") and/or "mesh-wire" tags be created and added to these questions, or are they not necessary?** If we decide not to create any of these new tags then it would definitely make sense to make "mesh" a synonym of [mesh-analysis](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mesh-analysis) since only mesh analysis questions would require a tag with "mesh" in the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has been no response other than a positive score to the question so I've made "mesh" a synonym of [mesh-analysis](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mesh-analysis). I have not created any other tags.